# Plotting a summation with 3 variables.

Tags: summation, numerical-methods, python, programming

How would one convert the following into a graph (programmatically):

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(-x^{2}\right)^{n}}{n !^{2 s}}
$$

... given that only the `n` is being varied by the summation sign?

Would it makes sense to hold the `x` and `s` constant while varying only the `n`, or must the `x`, `n` and `s` all be varied simultaneously (say using Python to generate the plot).

Comment: What do you mean by $dx$?

Comment: Oh sorry, that’s there because technically the whole thing gets integrated from negative to positive infinity, after the summation happens. Removed it.

Comment: So if you're integrating over $x$ this is a function only dependet of $s$ right? To plot $x$ and $s$ simultaniously you'd need a 3d plot.

Comment: That make sense. Although I was hoping to show the area under the curve/area.

Comment: Okay. To really visualize the area you want to integrate I recommend fixing $s$.